# Non-printable characters in this post

Tags: support, specific-question

What is going on [here](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/7385a539-f239-4416-861a-8d43654d41f2/view-source)? What character encoding is used? What could have caused this?

[Revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/2890961/revisions).

This is how it looks in my installation of Firefox, v. 3.6 (other browsers may try to display some graphic characters):

---

[alt text http://drmortensen.eu/SE20/FunnyCharacters_2010-05-23_16c.png](http://drmortensen.eu/SE20/FunnyCharacters_2010-05-23_16c.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says

> how to judge page that is refreshed?

in Japanese wide characters for english alphabet

Its UTF-8 encoding, but I think you just don't have the CJK Fonts.

[alt text http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/2700/7385a539.png](http://img42.imageshack.us/img42/2700/7385a539.png)